# Arrange it that someone + tense

Tags: tense

What tense do you think would fit the following sentences?

> Jake has arranged it that his daughter **will go** on a trip next week.
>
> Jake has arranged it that his daughter **is going** on a trip next week.
>
> Jake has arranged it that his daughter **goes** on a trip next week.
>
> Jake has arranged it that his daughter **go** on a trip next week.

Comment: Another option would be "... his daughter **should** go..."

Comment: I am missing your point. Do you mean that all of them are correct?

Comment: The last one is grammatically wrong. The others are fine.

Answer (score 2):

I would say

> Jake has arranged it **so** that his daughter **will go** on a trip next week

although I would be more likely to say

> Jake has arranged **for** his daughter **to go** on a trip next week.

Comment: Why didn't you explicitly point out whether the rest of the sentences are wrong or correct?

Comment: If you add in "so", I think the second and third could work, but not the last one.

Comment: "...arranged it that..." without "so" doesn't sound idiomatic to me.  There are hits for it on NGrams, but most of them are false positives (i.e. on closer inspection they're either "arranged it that way" or "...so arranged it that...").

Answer (score 1):

The fourth sentence is wrong: the word **that** introduces a clause, and a clause must have a main verb. **go** is either a bare infinitive (ie not a main verb) or present simple (in which case it should be **goes**.

All of the sentences are contrived: "arranged it [so] that" makes it sound like Jake has an evil plan, and needs his daughter away from home next week while he murders his wife, or robs a bank, or whatever.

A more natural sentence would be

> Jake has arranged for his daughter to go on a trip next week.